# Definitions errors. Am I missing a resource package?

Tags: resource-files, resources, server

I am a total beginner and I am being asked to edit something that has already been created.

I am having an error with undefined variables here:
[image: Description]

I was told these would be defined with a SharePoint Server 2013 install, which hasn't seem to work

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most probably *not* related to SharePoint but to general ASP.NET development. It looks like your .ascx and .ascx.cs files are not in sync (I mean: they're not linked by the mean of a parent/child class relationship as they should).
Maybe a problem of namespace or class name (see the tag `Inherit` in the .ascx file: does it match excatly the full class name in .ascs.cs?).

Comment: I think so. I took a screenshot of it all I believe. I really appreciate your help. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gxMi7DG.png)

Comment: As I mentioned, check whether the class name in the `Inherit` tag (.ascx) matches the full class name found in the .ascx.cs file.